# Limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\log(x)}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\log(x)}$$

I can see that it will be infinity as $x$ increases too fast then logx.
But how can I find it mathematically?
I tried using lhospital rule but as definition of lhospital rule says that it is allowed to use if answer of limit exists, but here answer is infinity so I think that I can not use it.
Please correct me in case I am wrong.
Thank you.

Edit1:

Can we use lhospita here or not. Will using lhospital will be valid or not.

Comment: yes l'Hospital is valid!

Comment: Since you are facing with an indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: But definition of lhospital rule says that we can use it only if result of lim exist. And in this case infinity does not exist.

Comment: @goloshailuoo It must be interpreted in a general sense that is that limit exist finite or infinite. Take also a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990941/lhospital-rule-requirement-that-the-limit-exists?rq=1

Comment: Limits equals to $\pm \infty$ are completely free to exist. When we think to a not existing limit we are dealing with limit such $sinx$ as $x+\infty$. In this case you can't define any limit.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$x=\exp(\log x)=1+\log x +\frac{(\log x)^2}2+\cdots>\frac{(\log x)^2}2$$
if $x>1$ and so
$$\frac x{\log x}>\frac{\log x}2$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but can I use lhospital rule or not?

Comment: @golushailuoo7 yes you can apply l'Hospital!

Answer (score 1):

By **substitution**

$$\frac x{\log x}=\frac {e^{\log x}}{\log x}=$$

set $\log x = y \to +\infty$

$$=\frac {e^{y}}{y}\stackrel{\text{definitively}}>\frac {y^2}{y}=y\to+\infty$$

You can also use **l'Hospital**:

> $$\frac x{\log x} \stackrel{\text{Hospital}}\implies\frac 1{1/x}=x\to+\infty$$

Comment: Gimusi. You are #1 !:)))P.S. I swear I did not copy!!!!

Comment: In any case we can say: "Repetita Juvant"!!! ;)

Comment: Gimusi. Bravo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\gt 4$ then $$\frac {x^2}{\log {x^2}}=\frac x2\cdot\frac x{\log x}\gt2\cdot \frac x{\log x}$$You can use this to show that the function is unbounded as $x\to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

$x \rightarrow +\infty.$

Let $x:=e^y; $

exponential fct. is bijective with $D= \mathbb{R}$, $R= (0,\infty).$

Consider for $y \gt 0$:

$F(y): =\dfrac{e^y}{y} = \dfrac{1+y + y^2/2! +...}{y}$

$\gt y/2.$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} F(y) =\infty.$

Comment: Nice Peter, that's also my solution without l'Hospital!

Comment: Thanks, gimusi. I noticed the similarity. Hopefully presented a bit differently.

Comment: Yes you have motivated in more detail why $e^y>y$ definitively.

Comment: That was the easy part.:))

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this is a simple high school limit?

One learns in high school that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log x}x=0^+$$
so the answer is obvious by the general rules for limits.

This standard limit is obtained  proving that
$$\forall x>1,\;0<\log x<2\sqrt x\quad\text{whence}\quad 0<\frac{\log x}x <\frac1{\sqrt x}.$$